# Вставить игру на сайт

Tags: html, css

Есть код игры с карточками ( [Codepen](https://codepen.io/samerpik/pen/daIDC) ) . 
Мне нужно её внедрить на сайт именно как игру, чтобы карточки работали так же, как и на codepen.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #333;
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url(https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/gplaypattern.png);
  background-position: center center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.5em 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #096AA3;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.animation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.pageTitle sup {
  font-size: .6em;
  color: #333;
}

.well {
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.well p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.content p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.cardContainer {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  /*depth of the elements */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  /*border: 1px solid #ff0000;*/
  padding-left: 1%;
}

.secondRow {
  margin-top: -1.4%
}

.card {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*transition effects */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped: {}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.card .back {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.card .back {
  background: #03446A;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}


/*Colors for front and back applied here*/

.cardContainer:first-child .card .front {
  background: #2aa9e0;
}

.cardContainer:first-child .card .back {
  background: #2aa9e0;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(2) .card .front {
  background: #f39c12;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(2) .card .back {
  background: #f39c12;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(3) .card .front {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(3) .card .back {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(4) .card .front {
  background: #AD103C;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(4) .card .back {
  background: #AD103C;
}

h3.cardTitle {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 8%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.content h3.cardTitle {
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 4%;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  h3.cardTitle {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: -15%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .card {
    height: 175px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 752px) {
  .secondRow {
    margin-top: -3%;
  }
  .cardContainer:nth-child(3),
  .cardContainer:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 390px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .secondRow {
    margin-top: -9%;
  }
  .well {
    padding: 1%;
  }
  .cardContainer:nth-child(3),
  .cardContainer:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  h3.cardTitle {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: -20%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .cardWrapper {
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <h1 class="pageTitle">3D Flip Card Effect</h1>
    <p>Advanced CSS3</p>
    <p>See live example at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.mymoodnotes.com/">mymoodcards</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">

    <!-- first Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">I was made with CSS3</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="happy"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">I was made with JQuery</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="laugh"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">Bootstrap is my mother</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="sick"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">Welldone!</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="sad"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- first Row End -->
  </div>
  <!--cardWrapper Ends-->

</div>
```

Comment: **ембиднуть** - классный термин! :)))

Comment: ...........))))))))))))))))

Comment: Прошу прощения за свой непрофесионализм, поэтому и обратился :)

Comment: @Андрей да  русский великий язык немного жалко :) можно ведь написать - встроить, добавить А так-то только приветствуются нормально оформленные вопросы

Comment: Там же есть возможность скопировать нужный код для вставки.

Comment: Снова извиняюсь, просто целый день с этим мучаюсь, принял правки какого-то добродеятеля, может быть теперь мне смогут помочь.

Comment: @MishaSaidov Да я уже архивом её даже скачал, но все никак не могу дойти как её вставить на сайт чтобы оно отображалось коректно как и на кодпене...

Answer (score 0):

А так? (тут не будет отображаться т.к. SO подрезает хеадеры запроса)

```html
<iframe height="265" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="3D Flip Card Effect" src="//codepen.io/samerpik/embed/daIDC/?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=css,resultundefined" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true">
  See the Pen <a href='https://codepen.io/samerpik/pen/daIDC/'>3D Flip Card Effect</a> by Samet Erpik
  (<a href='https://codepen.io/samerpik'>@samerpik</a>) on <a href='https://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.
</iframe>
```

Comment: Да суть в том что это "гиперссылка" на оригинал игры, а мне нужно чтобы оно работало так же как и на кодпене + внести некоторые правки.

Comment: @Андрей тогда вам остается только скопировать весь css, js, html себе на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что проблема в отображении блоков, для это нужно еще добавить стили bootstrap:

в `css`:

```
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

или таким способом в `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

потому как если берете код с codepen нужно обращать внимание на то что подключено еще в стилях и скриптах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #333;
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url(https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/gplaypattern.png);
  background-position: center center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.5em 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #096AA3;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.animation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.pageTitle sup {
  font-size: .6em;
  color: #333;
}

.well {
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.well p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.content p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.cardContainer {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  /*depth of the elements */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  /*border: 1px solid #ff0000;*/
  padding-left: 1%;
}

.secondRow {
  margin-top: -1.4%
}

.card {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*transition effects */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped: {}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.card .back {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.card .back {
  background: #03446A;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}


/*Colors for front and back applied here*/

.cardContainer:first-child .card .front {
  background: #2aa9e0;
}

.cardContainer:first-child .card .back {
  background: #2aa9e0;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(2) .card .front {
  background: #f39c12;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(2) .card .back {
  background: #f39c12;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(3) .card .front {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(3) .card .back {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(4) .card .front {
  background: #AD103C;
}

.cardContainer:nth-child(4) .card .back {
  background: #AD103C;
}

h3.cardTitle {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 8%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.content h3.cardTitle {
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 4%;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  h3.cardTitle {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: -15%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .card {
    height: 175px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 752px) {
  .secondRow {
    margin-top: -3%;
  }
  .cardContainer:nth-child(3),
  .cardContainer:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 390px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .secondRow {
    margin-top: -9%;
  }
  .well {
    padding: 1%;
  }
  .cardContainer:nth-child(3),
  .cardContainer:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  h3.cardTitle {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: -20%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .cardWrapper {
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <h1 class="pageTitle">3D Flip Card Effect</h1>
    <p>Advanced CSS3</p>
    <p>See live example at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.mymoodnotes.com/">mymoodcards</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">

    <!-- first Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">I was made with CSS3</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="happy"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">I was made with JQuery</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="laugh"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">Bootstrap is my mother</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="sick"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="cardTitle">Flip me!</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="cardTitle">Welldone!</h3>
              <br/>
              <p id="sad"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- first Row End -->
  </div>
  <!--cardWrapper Ends-->

</div>
```